# Need to add " ' " before number string

Tags: vba, numbers, format, concatenation, long-integer

I'm trying to select a column of numbers and append"'" to the front of them.  The reason is that the number strings are large and for some reason in similar files the numbers start changing on their own.  Particularly "0", "4" and "7".  Now I'm getting the data right from a CSV and when reformatting and parsing the data it SEEMS to be ok and not showing that issue BUT my understanding is that adding "'" before all the numbers will protect them from Excel auto changing them. What I'm trying to do is create a columns beside it that appends the values then delete the original column.  This works BUT creates the problem of changing the numbers to scientific and doesn't let me fix them.   All I'm trying to do is make it so the numbers cant get reformatted and start changing on their own.  So I'm open to all solutions.  The one below was an attempt to concatenate "'" to the front of the string.  IE "="'"&F2"

SO I have the following:

```
 Stop
 Columns("F").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For Each cel In Range("E:E" & lastRow)
         If cel <> "" Then cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "'" & cel
        On Error Resume Next
    Next cel
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *"adding "'" before all the numbers will protect them from Excel auto changing them"*. No, Excel does not "Auto-Change" anything if not *instructed* to do so, via some formula or some connection. Adding `'` only forces the cell to be interpreted as a string

Comment: I've seen articles to the contrary when the number strings are in excess of some threshold.  Regardless if "someone" gets into the file will adding " ' " forcing the string interpretation prevent them from hitting any formatting changes that will cause the changing phenomenon?

Comment: Excel doesn't handle numbers beyond 15 digits. Anything beyond position 15 becomes a 0. Can't imagine there would be any issue caused by any particular digit. What happens when you run that code?

Comment: You should change the column E to **Text** format before getting the data from CSV as June7 points out 15 digit limit. Or may be whole worksheet to be Text format. e.g. `Columns("E").NumberFormat = "@"`.

Comment: When bringing in data from a CSV where there might be issues with (eg) large numeric values which get truncated or lose precision or leading zeros, it's best to use the data >> from text function, which allows you to specify data types per-column *before* the data is populated on the sheet.  It's often too late to fix things after the data is on the worksheet.

Comment: @A.S.H - yes we might say this behavior is "as designed/expected" but we should also keep in mind that the vast majority of Excel users do not expect it.

Comment: @TimWilliams you're right, I wasn't expecting OP was talking about such big numbers during the import phase.

Comment: Thanks guys.  it seems that the macro I built to convert from CSV to XLSX circumnavigates the problem.  All workbooks converted don't display the problem.  It looks like just parsing as text seems to have solved it.  However on the first workbook, for posterity sake, adding ANY character before the number was the only way to make it stop.  altering Data type didn't have a permanent effect.